# Access Textfield Name Using Variable (Dynamically)

Tags: c#, dynamic, textfield

I'm currently working on an Windows Phone 7 App

I have at least 9 Textfields with the name `"TEXTFIELD_ID_1" , "TEXTFIELD_ID_2"` etc...
There will be more.

I want to access every of these fields with a loop:

```
if (currentpage == 1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i<10; i++)
    {
        string[] beitrag = result.Split(new string[] { "<split_inner>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        profile_img_1.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("EXAMPLE.jpg);               
    }
}
```

As you can see I access Image one using the direct way (1).
How can I use my variable "i" to access the image / textfield ?

Thx

Comment: I removed "C#" from the title since it is also a tag. See "http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles" for information on that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If names are regular like that then just use:

```
string name = "TEXTFIELD_ID_" + i;
this.Controls[name].Text = "bla bla bla...";
```

The key point is the `ControlCollection`. `this` refers to your `Form`.You can access a Form Control with it's `name` or `index`.

Edit: In WP7 you must have a container like a `Grid`. For example if you have a grid control named `LayoutRoot`, you can access your elements with `Children` property.If you want loop through your TextBoxes you can use `OfType` extension method:

```
var elements = LayoutRoot.Children;

foreach (var element in elements.OfType<TextBox>())
{
     var currentTextBox = element as TextBox;
     ...
}
```

Comment: I think this is what would work, but I get the message that theres no definition for "Controls" - I'm really new to wp7 - Can you help me on that?

Comment: isn't this winForms ? where did you put this code ?

Comment: @FrankProvost I understand.But I have no experince with wp7 :( I can't help you sorry.

Comment: @FrankProvost I have updated my answer it might help.

Comment: I don't get an error, however, I don't get a result^^ -> The for loop doesnt start

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in your loop:

```
if (currentpage == 1)
{
    for(int i = 1; i<10; i++)
    {
        string[] beitrag = result.Split(new string[] { "<split_inner>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Control imgControl = FindControl(string.Format("profile_img_{0}", i));
        imgControl.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter()
                                 .ConvertFromString("EXAMPLE.jpg);
    }
}
```

Comment: sry, i forgot to mention it's windowsphone 7